# Cant Play the Video in Custome Tableview Cell

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, uitableview

I create the Costume Cell in cell container, I need to play the Video But I tried with My code its Shows empty ..

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VedioCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

        let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4")
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = cell.bounds

        cell.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()



        return cell
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

```
    let cell: FeedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VedioCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

    let player = playerArray[indexPath.row]
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200)
   cell.PlayerView?.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
```

}